# Set Google Analytics default report

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to set default report for all properties and views?
I'm used to track traffic changes through "Acquisition > All traffic > Channels" report. And when I was switching between properties and views report stayed the same, but now it changes to "Audience > Overview" report. Can I somehow set "Acquisition > All traffic > Channels" report as default report for all my properties and views?

EDIT:
So I reached out to google support about this issue, here is the answer:

> I understand that you are facing issue with retaining the same report when you switch between views/properties in your Analytics account. This is due to an ongoing technical issue with the new Analytics interface. Since it has been recently transitioned to the new interface, we are continuously identifying opportunities to help improve the product.
>   There is no fixed timeline for when the technical issue will be fixed, as of now. However, our engineering team has taken this up on priority and is working on this rigorously, since there are multiple accounts affected by this.
>   Meanwhile as a workaround, you can manually open the desired when transitioning through the different views.

Comment: Please add your answer below instead of as an edit and accept it when you can - thanks.

Comment: I'm closing this question because you have found the solution, but didn't put it in as an answer.